# Why is the output is repeated

Tags: javascript

```
var creditCheck = function(income) {
    if(income >= 100) {
        console.log("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.");
    } else {
        console.log("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.");
    }
};
creditCheck(75);
```

When I run this function it displays the following:
"Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."
"Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."
If I was to run it with 125 instead of 75 it would say the following:
"You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."
"Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."

Comment: This code works as it should. You must be calling creditcheck somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Try to add '\n', so that you can diffrentiate between previous console logs, its nothing but the previous logs

Answer (score 0):

Check out where you call the function and look for the problem there. Your function is not the problem, it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andy mentioned in a comment, you are probably calling checkCredit in another part of your code. My personal guess is that you're calling it when you're trying to assign it to an event:

```
div.onclick = creditCheck(); // the () call it now instead of assigning the function as callback for the click event
```

To identify where exactly you are calling it, you can use a debugger. Place a breakpoint at the begining of the function then check the call stack. The first call looks like it's the correct one, while the second will lead you straight to the problem. You have a debugger in Chrome, Firebug and even IE, so you're pretty much covered.

Alternatively, if you find a debugger hard to use, you can search the entire code for RegExp `/creditCheck\s*\(\)/g` in your editor of choice. I still advise you to go the debugger route because it will benefit you more in the future.